# InputStream from URL in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Trying to get a file from URL into InputStream element (with AsyncTask) and then use it, but so far unsuccessful. Are the parameters right for AsyncTask? Can I check InputStream like I did in my code or is it wrong and it will always return null? Any other changes I should make?

My code:

```
String url = "https://www.example.com/file.txt";
InputStream stream = null;

public void load() {
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);
    if (stream == null) {
        //fail, stream == null
    } else {
        //success
    }
}

class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, InputStream> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params){

    try {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        stream = url.openStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

EDIT2:
I fixed it.

```
public void load(){
    //some code
    DownloadTask dt=new DownloadTask();
    dt.execute("www.example.com");
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>{
    InputStream text;

    protected Void doInBackground(String...params){
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
            text = is;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        //use "text"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `AsyncTask` in the wrong way. Do **all** operations like download or server requests inside `doInBackground(String... params)` method.

Very important to know, that you should update your UI inside the `onPostExecute(..)` method. This method get called from UI-Thread.

Here is an example (pseudo code):

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, MyDownloadedData> {

    private MyDownloadedData getFromStream(InputStream stream){
        // TODO
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected MyDownloadedData doInBackground(String... params){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url);
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();

            MyDownloadedData data = getFromStream(stream);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something
        }
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyDownloadedData data) {
        //
        // update your UI in this method. example:
        //
        someLabel.setText(data.getName());
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //...
    }


}
```

Comment: I solved my problem (edited my question). Thanks for the tip that I need to update UI inside the onPostExecute() method! Pseudo code is a bit confusing for beginner like me because for my task (get inputstream in asynctask) I don't need preExecute, progressUpdate, getFromStream() - all this stuff isn't relevant to the task.